# Can you save a project using an ArcGIS Online Web App as a user without an account?

Tags: arcgis-online, editing

Once I make my web app publicly accessible, is there a way for users to save a project they're working on?

For example, an agricultural planning adviser is making a map of a farm they're visiting. They've drawn some polygons of the farm, made buffers around streams etc. - Can they save their work at this point and return to it at a later date?

Comment: How are the users accessing the data? Are they logging into AGOL or are they accessing the maps as is through the browser? An option would be to create a public polygon layer, allowing everyone to edit. It will not save the map they working on, but the polygon will be visible next time they go to the same site. Problem is everyone will be able to edit this and it can get messy.

Comment: They would not have an AGOL account. I have provided all the data and layers they need in the web app and they would just access it through their browser. I came across the option you mentioned but I don't think it would work in this case because as you said, it would get very messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess, from reading the FAQ is that if you do not have an ESRI ArcGIS Online Account, you cannot save web maps.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/save-maps.htm

The wording here:

"*You must be the owner of a map to edit and save changes to it*."

and

"*Save a copy of someone else's map. This creates a copy of the map, and you are the owner of it. You can now edit and save changes to this new map.*"

To me, implies you need an account to make changes and save maps.

A solution, depending on your account level and the number of users you are allowed. Also if you know who the users are (i.e.: They are within your "trust" level and aren't members of the general public)

Would be to:

1. Make a generic account under your organisation
2. Create a group and add this generic account to that group
3. Share that single map with the group
4. Allow the users of the group to edit and save this map.

The users can the login and make the maps as they need, saving them with a standard you can determine - ie: Name_Site_Date etc...